# Vue-Formulate reset does not re-trigger validation message

Tags: vue.js, vue-formulate

This example shows a very small form made with vue-formulate:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-formulate-reseting-form-does-not-initiate-validation-message-again-yxruq

The input field takes a string of at least 4 of characters. Upon hitting submit, the form is reset via

```js
this.$formulate.reset(‘[name-of-the-form]‘)
```

It does indeed clear the form. But the validation message does not appear again.

What has to be done to fix this? Or could this be a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `$formulate.resetValidation()` method is a bit over aggressive depending on the validation behavior assigned. You can "undo" this by applying a ref to the form, and then explicitly iterating over the registry:

```html
<FormulateForm
  ...
  ref="form"
>
```

```js
// in your submit handler:
this.$refs.form.registry.map((input) => {
  input.formShouldShowErrors = true;
})
```

Updated reproduction: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-formulate-reseting-form-does-not-initiate-validation-message-again-forked-kn12h?file=/src/components/Reproduction.vue

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work! – A "return true" is needed to make eslint happy.